# Binding List Item array to repeater

Tags: c#, arrays, repeater, listitem

Olá eveyone,

I have a datasource which returns a single row like this:

```
Group        Roles
1            4,3,2
```

now, I need to translate that into a repeater like this:

```
GroupName

Admin        (know more)
Doctor       (know more)
Support      (know more)
```

when user clicks on `know more` then imma show them the right page. all is okay, only, since my DataSet is a single row, I Was wondering how to do this. I have an enum with those roles so translating numbers to roles is not a problem.

I was thinking split that string `4,3,2` into array and bind it to repeater. but I need the group name as well.

so I want something like `ListItem(GroupName, Role)` for each of the roles. so list item is great. or keyvalue pair array.

I am confused which is the best one to use in this scenario? if I should use `ListItem array`, can I bind it to repeater?

Answer (score 0):

You will be fine using an array as a datasource for your DataGrid. From the [DataGrid documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.datasource.aspx):

> The following data sources are valid:
>
> A DataTable
>
> A DataView
>
> A DataSet
>
> A DataViewManager
>
> Any component that implements the
>   IListSource interface
>
> **Any component that implements the
>   IList interface**

You can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) that array implements IList.

As for getting the name of your role, you can use the [Enum.GetName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname.aspx) method:

```
Enum.GetName(TypeOf(RoleEnumType), role_id)
```

Comment: this did not answer my question AT ALL. question: `what is the right way to convert a csv to multiple row and bind it to a repeater` ?

Comment: What you suggested was perfectly fine (get out the values using String.Split)